# proving inequality $\frac{(x+y)^{1/2}+(x+z)^{1/2}+(y+z)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{(x+y+z)}}<\sqrt{6}$ for all real x, y, z

Tags: inequality

I've been asked to prove this inequaltiy $$\dfrac{(x+y)^{1/2}+(x+z)^{1/2}+(y+z)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{(x+y+z)}}<=\sqrt{6}$$

$x, y, z$ are real numbers, $x + y + z\neq 0$

Every time I try the result is nothing.

I appreciate writing  proof, but the hint or showing the road(first step) is huge help.

Thank you.

Comment: This does not hold. For $x=y=z=10^{-100}$ the left hand side is $\approx 10^{50}$, for $x=y=z=10^{100}$ it is $\approx 10^{-50}$.

Comment: @amWhy You kept the wrong inequality.

Comment: Did I edit this correctly?

Comment: Sorry, both are wrong for homogeneity reasons... Maybe a square root in the denominator as well?

Comment: I was looking at the title: the x, y, z at the end in the body were part of $x, y, z$ are real numbers. Title: "((x+y)^.5 +(x+z)^.5+(y+z)^.5)/(x+y+z)>(6^.5) for every Real x, y, z"

Comment: Yes, I agree, with @Did: did you mean to say $\sqrt{x + y + z}$ for the denominator, toresi? Review the problems statement, and give us some feedback, or edit, to correct any errors in transcribing the problem...the current problem cannot be true if $(x + y + z) \leq 0$

Comment: Thanks for elegant editing, however  all of the right side under square root see [IMG]http://i47.tinypic.com/261kemb.gif[/IMG]
My mistake sorry

Comment: Is the $\sqrt{6}$ correct?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Last question: do you mean to use the "$\gt$" symbol, toresi? (Just want to be sure you get the correct help you're seeking).

Comment: @toresi Why don't you finally correct your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt{x+y}$, $b=\sqrt{y+z}$, $c=\sqrt{x+z}$.
Then you want to show 
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{x+z}+\sqrt{y+z}}{3}=\frac{a+b+c}3\le \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}3}=\sqrt{\frac{2(x+y+z)}{3}},$$
which is just the inequality between arithmetic and quadratic mean.

*Remark:* In the inequality between arithmetic and quadratic mean, we have equality iff $a=b=c$, hence iff $x=y=z$.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, the inequality to prove might be
$$
\sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{y+z}+\sqrt{z+x}\leqslant\sqrt{6}\cdot\sqrt{x+y+z},
$$
for **nonnegative** $x$, $y$ and $z$.

To prove this, note that the function $u:a\mapsto\sqrt{a}$ is concave on $a\geqslant0$ hence, for every nonnegative $a$, $b$, $c$,
$$
\frac{u(a)+u(b)+u(c)}3\leqslant u\left(\frac{a+b+c}3\right),
$$
and apply this inequality to $a=y+z$, $b=z+x$, $c=x+y$.

Comment: you should metion and provide reference to the inequality [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) you are using.

Comment: @achillehui Should I?

Comment: you should at least mention the name of inequality you are using. When OP encounter similar problem, he/she will hopefully know what to do (instead of asking same question here).